# Data Cleaning, refining etc

Tags: data-mining, data, data-cleaning

I have data as below:

```
Carpanter
Carepnter
Carpentor
Labourer
Labor
Labour
Housewife
House Wife
housewife.
```

I want to clean data and rectify the spelling mistakes but not manually because its a huge data. Due to spelling mistakes these 50/60 occupations have become around 2000.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is **text normalization**, which is a part of **NLP pipeline**.

To successfully preprocess your data, please try this below:

1. Install ekphrasis

   ```
   pip install ekphrasis
   ```
2. Apply seg & spell correction:

   ```
   from ekphrasis.classes.spellcorrect import SpellCorrector
   from ekphrasis.classes.segmenter import Segmenter
   sp = SpellCorrector(corpus="English")
   seg_eng = Segmenter(corpus="English") 

   words_to_correct = ['Carpanter','Carepnter','Carpentor','Labourer','Labor','Labour','Housewife','House Wife','housewife.']
   for word in words_to_correct:
       segmented = seg_eng.segment(word)
       corrected = sp.correct(segmented)
       print(word + " -> " + corrected)
   ```

Outputs as:

```
Carpanter -> carpenter
Carepnter -> carpenter
Carpentor -> carpenter
Labourer -> labourer
Labor -> labor
Labour -> labour
Housewife -> housewife
House Wife -> housewife
housewife. -> housewife
```

<sub>Note: Check [this](https://github.com/cbaziotis/ekphrasis/) amazing work and [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S17-2126) if you are interested in!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pyenchant](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant), this can be

```
import enchant
dictionary = enchant.Dict('en_US')
print(dictionary.suggest('word_to_be_checked'))
```